# yammer rest api error 429 while pulling user information

Tags: yammer, http-status-code-429

We are facing issue sometimes while pulling the information from yammer.
following is the error

```
    https://www.yammer.com/oauth2/access_token.json?client_id=q1gKtZ6UyinT6WWYqTEoag&client_secret=xYKbPYYJLX5U6cyjPuUEdq9DMfKCixXBo7QaGw4QHuU&code=CZnZejAnylQITtsVN7wxVw
```

[[31merror[0m] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 429 : null
[[31merror[0m] application -

Answer (score 1):

You are exceeding the rate limits when you are pulling data. See below

> API calls are subject to rate limiting. Exceeding any rate limits will result in all endpoints returning a status code of 429 (Too Many Requests). Rate limits are per user per app. There are four rate limits:

- Autocomplete: 10 requests in 10 seconds.
- Messages: 10 requests in 30 seconds.
- Notifications: 10 requests in 30 seconds.
- All Other Resources: 10 requests in 10 seconds.

https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/rest-api-rate-limits